# json schema enum display titles

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to create a json schema for a field that contains an enum, and I want the enum values to be the uuids of the options, but still provide display titles for the user to actually select from. I don't see how to do this within the json schema spec, am I missing something? My initial instinct is to just make the enum property a map instead of an array, but the spec seems pretty clear about it being an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a json-schema into a form requires more data than fits in the specification of json-schema, but there are ways to tweak it within the specification.

You could use oneOf instead of enum, and give each oneOf object a title.

Else, you could add a property enumNames, being a map of enum value to name.  (The specification allows extra properties.)

For more complex forms, you will probably still need a form specification outside of the json-schema.  You could look at form generators like [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form) that uses one schema and one form-definition.

Comment: enumNames is proposed: https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/enumNames-(v5-proposal)